# $.Ajax POST, accessing return data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, callback

I'm currently working on a ASP.NET Webforms site and I've run in to a small problem. Been searching around for 2 hours now and I got a deadline, so hoping someone here can assist.

On my .cs file I have the following Webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
   public static string IsJobEditable(int jobid)
   {
       try
       {
           string isEditable = "false";

           JobsBLL jbl = new JobsBLL();

           int jobStatusId = jbl.GetJobStatusId(jobid);


           if(jobStatusId == Convert.ToInt32(ConstantsUtil.JobStatus.Waiting) || jobStatusId == Convert.ToInt32(ConstantsUtil.JobStatus.Edit))
           {
               isEditable = "true";
           }

           return isEditable;


       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {

           throw ex;
       }
   }
```

This function in this case will ALWAYS return TRUE as a string.

On Aspx page I have the following

```
$(function () {

           $.ajax({

               type: "POST",
               url: "Coordination.aspx/IsJobEditable",
               data: "{jobid:" + jobid + "}",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "text",
               success: function (result) {

                   alert(result);


                   // This is written out in the alert {"d":"true"}
                   // I want this in a variable as a string
                   // so I can do a check on it before I do some other actions
                   // The format is not a String so i cannot split on it to 
                   // retrieve the "true" part.

               },
               error: function (err, result) { alert(err); }

           });
       });
```

As you can see in the comments the value I get back in the Callback method is in to me a weird format. The type is unknown and I need this value to be able to proceed with my entire method surrounding the small portion of the Javascript.

So can anyone point me into the direction where I can access the result variable / data as a var or anything else that will let me put it into a var (as a string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved it:

```
$(function () {

       $.ajax({

           type: "POST",
           url: "Coordination.aspx/IsJobEditable",
           data: "{jobid:" + jobid + "}",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (result) {

               alert(result.d);

               //I finally got the data string i wanted
               var resultAsString = result.d;

           },
           error: function (err, result) { alert(err); }

       });
   });
```

So 2 things were done to solve this. I had to change the dataType to "json" and I used the result.d to retrieve my data.

What threw me off was the lack of intellisens on the result object. But the .d (data) property however solved it.

Thanks you to all who contributed to this answer.

Answer (score 5):

Use result.d to get your string.

See this site for an explanation of the .d issue when calling .ajax from ASP.NET:  http://encosia.com/2009/02/10/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/

Answer (score 2):

try alert(result.d);

Answer (score 2):

You can easily retrieve the "true" part like this:

```
alert(result.d);
```

The reason the object is wrapped in the "d" json object is security. You can read about it for example [here](http://encosia.com/2009/06/29/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/).

Answer (score 1):

According to [two](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/) [articles](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/04/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks.aspx) I found, I think you want to specify "DataType" as json not as text (since you're expecting a content-type of json to be returned). That may be your issue, though i don't have a sample project in front of me to test on. Your result is also probably `result.d` as outlined in those same articles.